# file downloading in c#/xaml metro apps in WebView control

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am developing a metro style app. I am using WebView control for accessing the website. Now when I want to download something, I can't get popup for saving it, what I get is just blank page.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this MSDN Social conversation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/winappswithcsharp/thread/98d4fab5-0ba0-41cd-83ba-4dbf548f9ffe), what you want is not possible.

*Hpcd (Partner)*:

> Hi I loaded an external web page into WebView. The page contains a
>   link to download a file. When I click the link nothing happens. If I
>   click regular links to other html pages, it does redirects. In Metro
>   IE, a command charm opens with Run, Save, Cancel buttons when you
>   click on a link to download. How can I do this from WebView? Thanks

*Matt SmallMicrosoft (MSFT)*:

> You can't do this.